# Use of big name apps in a commercial video projects

Tags: video-editor, video-recording, production, legal

Does anyone know the legal side of including obvious brands such as Facebook/Instagram in commercial video projects? Or replicating a Facebook messenger motion graphic? For example, visuals of Young adults scrolling through an Instagram feed or typing into messenger to promote sharing of content? Are their licenses for these things or is it fine to use without in video projects?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll probably get better advice on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm no legal expert, certainly - so do take this 'advice' with a pinch of salt - and I'm not sure what you mean by commercial, but I'd probably err on the side of caution and, instead of replicating a Facebook post exactly, just do an approximation of it with motion graphics if you've got the time/budget.

To be honest, though, unless this is going out on TV, you're probably fine to use FB/Insta/Whateveragram provided that you're not suggesting that you're affiliated in any way and that those programs aren't the cause of crime/immoral action in the film.